# How does ruby's String .hash method work?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm just a newbie to ruby. I've seen a string method (String).hash .

For example, in `irb`, I've tried

```
>> "mgpyone".hash
```

returns

```
=> 144611910
```

how does this method works ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `hash` method is defined for all objects. See [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-hash):

> Generates a `Fixnum` hash value for this
>   object. This function must have the
>   property that `a.eql?(b)` implies `a.hash == b.hash`.
>   The hash value is used by class `Hash`. Any hash value that
>   exceeds the capacity of a `Fixnum` will
>   be truncated before being used.

So the `String.hash` method is defined in [C-Code](http://ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/string_8c-source.html#l00852). Basically (over-simplified) it just sums up the characters in that string.

Comment: One thing to realize is that if you run a program more than once, the hashes change. That is, it's not just computing a hash based on the characters contained in the string. E.g., try doing ruby -e "print 'a'.hash" twice in a row. If you want a reproducible hash, you can use something like Digest::MD5.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to get a consistent hashing output I would recommend NOT to use `'string.hash` but instead consider using [Digest::MD5](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/MD5.html) which will be safe in multi-instance cloud applications for example you can test this as mentioned in comment in previous by @BenCrowell

Run this 2x from your terminal, you will get different output each time:

```
ruby -e "puts 'a'.hash"
```

But if you run this the output will be consistent:

```
ruby -e "require 'digest'; puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest 'a'"
```